# Add data from array to the one textarea as paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

`"items":{
    "item1":"here is some text that should be paragraph1",
    "item2":"here is some text that should be paragraph2",
    "item3":"here is some text that should be paragraph3",
 }`

Need to have two parts for this:
1. as a separated paragraphs, that are shown on the page
  `<section class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11"  ng-repeat="x in items">
           <h3>Item {{$index+1}}</h3>
           <p>{{x}}</p>
   </section>`

2. need to get all paragraphs as one `<textarea>` for edit.

Is it possible - or probably better to put the items together and then split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with adding each paragraph as a textarea and hide if empty.